# How can i use defined strings within my string

Tags: c#, string

Uhh Sorry its really hard to explain but.

This is already a string:

```
"login_username=Username&login_password=Password&login_submit=Submit"
```

How can i replace 'Username' with a pre-defined string called User? Would it require Quotes?

Comment: you may add your intent, so the answers will focus the right direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean you have a string *variable* called `user`? If so, something like:

```
string parameters = "login_username=" + user + 
                    "&login_password=Password&login_submit=Submit";
```

Or, better:

```
string parameters = string.Format(
      "login_username={0}&loginPassword={1}&login_submit=Submit",
      user, password);
```

Or you *could* use (if you can't change the code and *have* to take the original string with the hard-coded user name):

```
string updated = fixedParameters.Replace("login_username=Username",
                                         "login_username=" + user);
```

Answer (score 2):

Tor replace Strings with Strings you use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx).

```
var str  = "login_username=Username&login_password=Password&login_submit=Submit";
var str2 = str.Replace("Username", "User");
```

or if your `User` is a string variable:

```
str2 = str.Replace("Username", User);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string str="login_username=Username&login_password=Password&login_submit=Submit";
str User="Hamlet";
str.Replace("Username",User);
```

Or if you don't have str pre-defined you can write like this

```
string User= "Hamlet";
string str= "login_username=" + userName + "&login_password=Password&login_submit=Submit"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to concatenate strings, right?

```
string userName = "SomeUserName";
string value = "login_username=" + userName + "&login_password=Password&login_submit=Submit"
```